# file.copy: overcoming Windows long path/filename limitation

Tags: r, windows

I have a table in R containing many files that I need copied to a destination folder. The files are spread out over dozens of folders, each several sub-folders down. I have successfully used the following code to find all of the files and their locations:

`(fastq_files <- list.files(Illumina_output, ".fastq.gz", recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE) %>% as_tibble)`

After appending the full path, I have a tibble that looks something like this:

| full_path |
| --- |
| Q:/IlluminaOutput/2019/091119 AB NGS/Data/Intensities/BaseCalls/19-15897-HLA-091119-AB-NGS_S14_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz |
| Q:/IlluminaOutput/2019/091119 AB NGS/Data/Intensities/BaseCalls/19-15236-HLA-091119-AB-NGS_S14_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz |
| Q:/IlluminaOutput/2018/062818AB NGS/Data/Intensities/BaseCalls/18-06875-HLA-062818-NGS_S11_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz |

Using the `file.copy` function gives an error that the file name is too long, a known issue in Windows (I am using RStudio on Windows 10).

I found that if I set the working directory directory to the file location, I am able to copy files. Starting with a table like this:

| file | path |
| --- | --- |
| 19-14889-HLA-091119-AB-NGS_S14_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz | Q:/IlluminaOutput/2019/091119 AB NGS/Data/Intensities/BaseCalls/ |
| 19-14889-HLA-091119-AB-NGS_S14_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz | Q:/IlluminaOutput/2019/091119 AB NGS/Data/Intensities/BaseCalls/ |
| 18-09772-HLA-062818-NGS_S11_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz | Q:/IlluminaOutput/2018/062818AB NGS/Data/Intensities/BaseCalls/ |
| 18-09772-HLA-062818-NGS_S11_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz | Q:/IlluminaOutput/2018/062818AB NGS/Data/Intensities/BaseCalls/ |

I used the following code to sucsessfully copy the first file:

```
(dir <- as.character(as.vector(file_and_path[1,2])))
setwd(dir)
(file <- as.character(as.vector(file_and_path[1,1])))
(file.copy(file, Trusight_output) %>% as.tibble)
```

I got this to work, but I don't know how to apply these steps to every column in my table. I think i probably have to use the `lapply` function, but I'm not sure how to construct it.

Comment: Have you tried using UNC path names? They should have no issue with length.

Comment: @KonradRudolph No? You mean `\\?` paths, not UNC.

Comment: @Anders Yes,  I mean `\\?\ `. (You’re right that they’re device paths, not UNC paths, but the MSDN has variously called those UNC paths as well, and the designator has stuck.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying to replace every instance of `/` in the path name with `\\?\` Stackoverflow doesn't like how I'm typing this. Replace "/" with "\\?\"

Comment: They mean to prefix the path with `\\?\ `, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd). I'm not sure that it will work, though. The source code of `file.copy` contains an explicit test [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/f282c703d29c0cb4b580ef8821dbb2e5b0a1b0ca/src/main/platform.c#L2677-L2679). (Unless you were also suggesting to _not_ use `file.copy`, @KonradRudolph?)

Comment: AFAICT, if you want to do `file.copy(from, to)`, then you need `from`, `to`, and `file.path(to, basename(from))` to be less than 260 characters.

Comment: @MikaelJagan Ah, it hadn’t occurred to me that the implementation of `file.copy` would do something so ill-advised. Yeah, that won’t work then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick, assuming that `file_and_path$file` and  `file_and_path$path` are both character vectors and that `Trusight_output` is an absolute path:

```r
f <- function(file, from, to) {
    cwd <- setwd(from)
    on.exit(setwd(cwd))
    file.copy(file, to)
}
Map(f, file = file_and_path$file, from = file_and_path$path, to = Trusight_output)
```

We use `Map` here rather than `lapply` because we are applying a function of more than one argument. FWIW, operations like this are often better suited for PowerShell.